# How to import excel file in web page useing Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

We are trying to open an existing excel file (2003) from server location in a web page and save it again in the same location using following syntax.

```
Set ExcelReportApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelReportApp.Workbooks.Open("http://bocntgcasd10/AppPortfolioCatalogrnd/Templates/DatabasesList.xls")
```

It executes properly with out showing any error, but not showing any page i.e. web page is blank with DONE status.

Please let me know how to import or open the files (Temple) in my web page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little ambiguous as to where the code you've posted is actually running.

If the code is running server-side I don't know why you wouldn't expect a blank web page, you aren't actually sending anything to the client.

If the code is running client-side you should be getting an error in script because this sort of operation is most likely blocked the browser (in IE you will see the small yellow warning triangle at the bottom left in the status bar).  Again that would result in a blank web page.

Comment: This code is for server-side as it is written in vb script. Do you have any Idea, how to open the excel sheet from server location.

Comment: You can navigate directly to it from a browser or even the file open dialog of Excel.  If you want to be saving over the existing file then you need to be looking into WebDAV.